# What does array_filter without a callback do?

Tags: php, arrays

I just came across this code:

```
array_filter(array_map('intval', $array));
```

It seems to return all entries of $array converted to int where the number is > 0.

However, I can't see on the manual page that this is defined. It is supposed to return the array value if the callback function evaluates to true. But there isn't any callback function defined here.

Confusing is also that the callback function is optional on [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: `array_filter` usually just removes empties (or equivalent) in your array if no callback.

Comment: This is extracted from manual ***If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed***.

Comment: Yes, cheers, I overlooked it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Removes empty or equivalent values from array:

```
$entry = array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => false,
    2 => -1,
    3 => null,
    4 => '',
    5 => 0
);
    
print_r(array_filter($entry));
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
)
```

See the [original documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#example-6190) from the manual:
**Example #2 array_filter() without callback**

Comment: What is the merit of the approved suggested edit (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have added a 0 to the $entry array to show that array_filter($entry) function also filters(removes) the value 0 (besides false, null and empty string ' ')

Answer (score 10):

If you read just a little further on the page to which you linked, you find, "If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed."